# Processing in memory List using parallel library foreach and contention issues

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a List that I need to process in parallel .

I have written some parallel code that goes through this list and produces a file for a third party to use.

How can I avoid a situation where more that one thread will try to process the same file.

I came up with this solution

Create 2 Lists.(Not sure which type of collection is better for working with parallel library.)

1.Master List where all the "customers" are located `List<Customer>`

2.ProcessedList that contains all the files that having been processed `ConcurrentBag<string>`.

My solution would be (dummycode)

```
  Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(MasterList, parOpts, (customer, loopState) =>
                    {
                        if (cancelToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            cancelToken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        }

                        count = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

                        if (!processedList.Contains(customer.CustomerId))
                        {
                            DoSomething(customer, count);
                            processedList.Add(customer.CustomerId);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                   etc....
                }
            }
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: This looks like you're on the wrong track regarding file contention. It might be better if you post what you're trying to do with the files.

Comment: you don't need the `if` for `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` it internally has that exact `if` statement inside it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I didnt know that,I have seen many examples implementing that

Comment: @CoryNelson That is exactly what I am trying to do. I have an in memory list of customer objects and we need to save each of them to an xmlfile.I want to avoid at the start multiple thread trying to grab the same object from the list.I wish you could expand a bit more because your comment is very very vague.If I could remove from my masterList as I go along I would not need the "ProcessedList".But I guess you cannot remove an item from a collection you are looping.What would your approach be.Any code snippets?

Comment: @user231465, you may want to describe your data model better. Maybe, include some infographic picture. Why the same file can be seen multiple times in the list?

Comment: @Noreratio ,Hi thanks for your reply,there is nothing more to describe really.All I was wondering if by processing an in memory list on parallel some threads can process the same item more than once and how I can prevent it.